# calendar sharing based on role or profile

Tags: lightning, sharing, public-calendar

I have a requirement where the calendars should be shared based on role/profiles. For eg: I have a profile named Marketing. This Marketing profile user's calendar should be shared with Sales Manager Profile. Sales Manager Profile users can see Marketing profile user's Calendar.. I know I can do this using public calendars from  setup but I cannot find any button or option regarding this in Lightning.

In Lightning view, a calendar can be shared with a user but I need a calendar sharing in profile level. I have also gone through Salesfoce's PDF document but didn't find it helpful.

Can anyone help me solving this in detail.

Answer (score 2):

The spring 19 release gives you the feature **Keep Your Team Organized with Public Calendars in Lightning Experience**.

Use public calendars to keep team members in the loop and everyone’s projects on track more easily. Everyone who shares a public calendar can view, schedule, and update events without switching to Salesforce Classic. **share with public groups, roles, or people you want to share the calendar**. Previously, you could enable public calendars, but reps couldn’t access them from Lightning Experience.

Where: This change applies to Lightning Experience and all versions of the Salesforce app in Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer editions.

Why: Under Other Calendars in the side panel, sales reps can add and hide public calendars from their calendar view.

[image]

How: In Setup, enter Public Calendars and Resources in the Quick Find box and then click Public Calendars and Resources. Under Public Calendars, select New.

So, You can preview this feature in the sandbox by 4th January 2019. You can share with the role but not on Profile level.

Reference: [Keep Your Team Organized with Public Calendars in Lightning Experience](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_sales_productivity_calendar_public.htm)

Comment: Hello Sanket Kumar,
Thank you very much for your cincern over this issue. 
So that means Calendar sharing with roles is not yet available and will be available witgh spring'19 Update?
As of now, I can see only user level sharing in lightning.

Comment: Yes as of now,  it is not there.  It will come by spring 19 release.  You can preview it by signing for a preview org for spring 19 release.